# How does an LRU cache fit into the CAP theorem?

Tags: caching, design-patterns, database-design, lru, cap

I was pondering this question today. An LRU cache in the context of a database in a web app helps ensure **A**vailability with fast data lookups that do not rely on continually accessing the database.

However, how does an LRU cache in practice stay fresh? As I understand it, one cannot garuntee **C**onsistency along with **A**vailibility.  How is a frequently used item, which therefore does not expire from the LRU cache, handle modification? Is this an example where in a system that needs **C** over **A**, an LRU cache is not a good choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a cache too small to hold all the data (where an eviction might happen and the LRU part is relevant) is not a good example for the CAP theorem, because even without looking at consistency, it can't even deliver partition tolerance and availability at the same time. If the data the client asks for is not in the cache, and a network partition prevents the cache from getting the data from the primary database in time, then it simply can't give the client any answer on time.

If we only talk about data actually in the cache, we might somewhat awkwardly apply the CAP-theorem only to that data. Then it depends on how exactly that cache is used.

A lot of caching happens on the same machine that also has the authoritative data. For example, your database management system (say PostgreSql or whatever) probably caches lots of data in RAM and answers queries from there rather than from the persistent data on disk. Even then [cache invalidation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_invalidation) is a hairy problem. Basically even without a network you either are OK with sometimes using outdated information (basically sacrificing consistency) or the caching system needs to know about data changes and act on that and that can get very complicated. Still, the CAP theorem simply doesn't apply, because there is no distribution. Or if you want to look at it very pedantically (not the usual way of putting it) the bus the various parts of one computer use to communicate is not **p**artition tolerant (the third leg of the CAP theorem). Put more simply: If the parts of your computer can't talk to one another the computer will crash.

So CAP-wise the interesting case is having the primary database and the cache on separate machines connected by an unreliable network. In that case there are two basic possibilities: (1) The caching server might answer requests without asking the primary database if its data is still valid, or (2) it might check with the primary database on every request. (1) means consistency is sacrificed. If its (2), there is a problem the cache's design must deal with: What should the cache tell the client if it doesn't get the primary database's answer on time (because of a partition, that is some networking problem)? In that case there are basically only two possibilities: It might still respond with the cached data, taking the risk that it might have become invalid. This is sacrificing consistency. Or it may tell the client it can't answer right now. That is sacrificing availability.

So in summary

- If everything happens on one machine the CAP theorem doesn't apply
- If the data and the cache are connected by an unreliable network, that is not a good example of the CAP theorem, because you don't even get A&P even without C.
- Still, the CAP theorem means you'll have to sacrifice C or even more of A&P than the part a cache won't deliver in the first place.
- What exactly you end up sacrificing depends on how exactly the cache is used.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question exactly. I think the thing I was really worried about was cache invalidation, and this hit the nail on the head.